# Console Logging gone in TitaniumStudio

Tags: debugging, titanium, appcelerator

```
***Project Specs:***
iOS 4.3
Ti SDK 1.6.2
Titanium Studio
```

I've recently switched to Titanium Studio from Titanium Developer and after importing my project any references to Ti.API.info('some message') are completely ignored.

I searched the Appcelerator Q/A forums but all I found were people having the problem but no solution or reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- did you check your run configurations
  to make sure logging is turned on?
- also i am pretty certain you have to
  be using at least 1.7.x to use
  TiStudio, i might be wrong about that
  though

Comment: Does this mean that if I want to pass [INFO] messages to the console to track development I now have to pay for an appcelerator subscription? If so is there any way to get the Titanium Developer app back?

Comment: See this thread [http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121338/where-can-i-download-titanium-developer](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121338/where-can-i-download-titanium-developer)

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks Aaron, TiDev is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

TiStudio has multiples consoles running at the same time. To access them you need to be using Debug mode with 1.7.* or you can just click the small console icon multiple times to shuffle through each `Kroll` function console running.

In the picture in this [guide](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+the+Console+View) it's the fourth button from the right. The blue one.